# Smarty - How to add values from my form to mysql query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, smarty

I don't know how to pass values from form to mysql query using smarty.

Code body.tpl:

```
<form action="" name="training" id="training">
  <select name="city">
    <option value="ostrava">Ostrava</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="date_start" id="date_start" value="" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE city="<value from city>" AND date_start="<value from date_start>";
```

Comment: Yeah but where should I use it Can I use It in function.php when I include it not in .tpl itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access POST data with smarty by doing: `$smarty.post.[name]`.

So place of `"<value from city>"` place in: `..'".$smarty.post.city."'..`

And in place of `"<value from date_start>"` place in: `..'".$smarty.post.date_start."'..`

Note that you want to serialize your input. And this is assuming that your query is wrapped in `"..."` double quotes. For example the entire query would look like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE city='".$smarty.post.city."' AND date_start='".$smarty.post.date_start."'"
```

You will need to tell you form to look for POST values. just add `method='post'`:

```
<form ... method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Note you can also use GET, but POST is safer because the user can't change it in the URL.

Comment: this is plain simple wrong since <value from date_start> is in a string that is being sent to the mysql server and NOT the smarty engine!

Comment: @ITroubs `$smarty` can be used in PHP. I've made it clear that you need to add the string around it. Note that `{ ... }` in smarty simply means that you are writing PHP with the template engine.

Answer (score 0):

With `$smarty.get.city`. If you are using post method, then `$smarty.post.city`.

There is nothing to do with smarty.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
. " WHERE city='" . $smarty.get.city . "'"
. " AND date_start='" . $smarty.get.start_date . "'";
```

**NOTE**: Avoid sql injection by escaping your variables.

See this: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=75542

But i suggest you to do it on the PHP side, not in the template.

Comment: He also just could use $_REQUEST. That would include both methods.

Comment: I really do not like to use `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Any reason why? I am always interested in well argumented opinions

Comment: Because i have no control about the order of  `$_POST/$_GET` if I have no controll of `php.ini` (`variables_order`) file. `$_REQUEST` also includes the `$_COOKIE`. So, when i am programming, I do what i do, so i am using `$_POST` or `$_GET` directly. Of course you can handle it with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` but that is more work.

Comment: Can I use $smarty.post.name_of_my_input_or_selectbox in mysql query outside .tpl for example in functions.php when I include it ?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but you can simply try that out with a `var_dump()` function.

Comment: This is the normal way to do it in PHP, the OP asked for how you can do this in smarty.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I am lost :( Can U please tell me If I should use {php} mysql query {/php} in my .tpl I need to operate with values from my form body.tpl ?

Comment: Yes you can. I've updated my answer. But first check my link in answer. You need some preparation.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Is it safe connect to my database with login and password in .tpl ?

Comment: @user3105439 You need to tell your form send some data, you can use POST or GET. Place it as an attribute on your form.

Comment: @user3105439 Not if you don't serialize your input. Otherwise people can write SQL in your string. You will want to pass your data through: `mysqli_real_escape_string` and use prepared SQL statements at the least.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I use method="post" and action is on same page. Is it safe to use {php} mysql_connect, mysql_select_db, mysql_query and mysql_result {/php} in my .tpl file ?

Comment: I know mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: @user3105439 So we don't take up comments [lets move this to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65158/smarty-how-to-add-values-from-my-form-to-mysql-query)